# Load webserver context.xml using Spring

Tags: spring

Fairly new to Spring, so I'm having some trouble with this.  I'm trying to use LDAP security with Spring.  I can use a properties file I created inside the webapp itself.  But what I would like to do is load and read the context.xml file of the server (it has all the values I need for this and other applications).

This is what I have:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    </bean>   
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
        <property name="searchContextAttributes" value="true"/>
        <property name="contextOverride" value="true"/>
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
        <property name="locations">
            <list>

                <value>/WEB-INF/properties/dataUploadProperties.properties</value>
                <value>/WEB-INF/properties/globalProperties.properties</value>
                <value>context.xml</value>

            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I'm able to load and read the 2 properties files, but the context.xml is not found. Does it need to be the absolute path on the server?

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the first thing I would recommend is to use [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/). It has an already build in LDAP support.

---

> but the context.xml is not found

Normally this (reading the `context.xml` directly) is not the way you should go.
Instead, define some properties and or JNDI resources in the `context.xml` and then use them in the spring configuration.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- access via jndi -->
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="jndiEmailSession"
        jndi-name="java:comp/env/email/session/myEmailSession" />

    <!-- direct access for properties required the SERVLET contect property
         place older configurer, then it works like properties from normal
         property files -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">      <property name="locations" value="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties" />   </bean>

   <bean class=Demo>
      <property name="someString" value="${simpleValue}" />
   </bean>
</beans>
```

context.xml:

```
<Resource name="email/session/myEmailSession"
          type="javax.mail.Session"
          auth="Container"                          
    password="secret"
    mail.debug="false"
    mail.transport.protocol="smtp"  
    mail.smtp.auth="true"
    mail.smtp.user="test@example.com"
    mail.smtp.host="mail.example.com"
    mail.smtp.from="test@example.com"/>

 <Parameter name="simpleValue" value="any" override="false" />
```

Comment: I am using Spring Security. I'm trying to get the url for the LDAP from the servers context.xml file since each server has a different url.  Thanks

Comment: @Chris Mattmiller: in this case you should define the LDAP connection in the context.xml as an jndi ressource

Comment: If I use set it up as a jndi resource I get this error: Lexical error at line 1, column 1.  Encountered: "$" (36), after : ""